# Not getting dependencies to add for android project ,setting firebase for flutter project, not getting dependencies so that can copy in gradle file

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT2sY.png) 
not getting dependencies what to do next setting up firebase with flutter android app

setting firebase for flutter project(android), not getting dependencies so that i can copy in gradle file how to resolve this error .

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT follow those instructions in that page. That's for native android developers.

Instead, you should follow these steps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android